# How to create dynamic view in one page

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces

i have one page index.jsf, i was use ui:include for include header and footer,i want to dynamic view in content, it mean when user click on register link just content change header and footer didn't change

i image my code sample is:

```
<ui:include render="#{mybean.include}"/>
```

and in backing bean my code will :

```
public void getInclude(){
    if("page" == a){
        return "a.jsf";
    }
    else if("page" == b) {
     return "b.jsf";
    }
}
```

and i to use pretty url example
in old way jsf page will display url

```
http://localhost/index.jsf?page=a or http://localhost/index.jsf?page=b
```

but i want use pretty url instead of old way, example:

```
http://localhost/index/a
```

how can i do it (it mean using pretty faces and how i can use if-else for what?)
i can explain above question here
instead of above i use if("page"=a) if i use old way paste parameter url http://loalhost/index.jsf?page=a
but if i use pretter url or pretty faces what would i do for if-else statement?
if(?? = a)

2 question please help me thankyou

```
  ==========================================================
```

Now i set up pretty faces and work well but i dont know how can i get parameter from Prettyfaces, in Pretty-config.xml i was config page follow:

Main page ( content change dynamic in there)

```
<url-mapping id="mainpage">
 <pattern value="/home" />
 <view-id>/faces/main.xhtml</view-id> 
</url-mapping>
```

Page1

```
<url-mapping id="mainpage">
 <pattern value="/home/#{page:content1}" />
 <view-id>/faces/content1.xhtml</view-id> 
</url-mapping>
```

page 2

```
<url-mapping id="mainpage">
 <pattern value="/home/#{page:content2}" />
 <view-id>/faces/content2.xhtml</view-id> 
</url-mapping>
```

in page one i use ui:include for dynamic subview

```
<ui:include src=#{bean.includePage}/>
```

my bean have one method for get include page

```
  public String getIncludePage(){
       if(page == null){
        return "content.xhtml";
       }
       else if (page.equals(content1)){
        return "content1.xhtml";
      }
      else if (page.equals(content2)){
        return "content2.xhtml;
      } 
}
```

But i can't change dynamic page view content in one page

Comment: I would have answered "Use PrettyFaces". But you're apparently already aware about this. What's your problem with it? What have you done as far and at what step are you stucking while implementing PrettyFaces?

Comment: Hi Balus i was edit my question, Can you help me please ! Thank you

Comment: I am not sure about the prettyfaces part, but do you know that `==` won't compare strings by value but by reference? To compare two strings (as all other objects) on value, use `equals()` method.

Comment: Hi Balus i was fix it in my code,i think i wrong in somewhere, i was try to read tutorial, but not clear , i will try thank you very much ! Respect You!

Comment: i was solved this problem by here : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly your problem has nothing to do with PrettyFaces.

Is it correct that you want to end up with different pages which share the same header and footer? In this case you should really learn about templating with Facelets because this is exactly an usecase for it.

Here a short example on how Facelets work:

`template.xhtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<head>
  <title>
    <ui:insert name="title" />
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<div id="center">
  <ui:insert name="title" />
  <hr />
  <ui:insert name="content" />
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

`some-page.xhtml`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/template.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="title">My Page Title</ui:define>
  <ui:define name="content">

    <p>
      This is the main content area
    </p>

  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

I recommend to read [Facelets fits JSF like a glove](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-facelets/). It's an really great article on Facelets.